# Custom MvxAndroidSetupSingleton

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

There's `MvxAndroidSetupSingleton` class in MvvmCross what provides several virtual methods but at the same time has private only constructor

```
public class MvxAndroidSetupSingleton : MvxSingleton<MvxAndroidSetupSingleton>
{
    private MvxAndroidSetupSingleton()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void CreateSetup(Context applicationContext){}

    protected virtual Type FindSetupType(){}
}
```

I'd like to git rid of reflection-based implementation and to initialize `Setup` on my own, but don't see any way to do that (due to the private constructor). Is there any way to handle that?

Or at least would be glad to know reason of existing virtual methods in class with private constructor.

Comment: Why would you like to initialize it on your own?

Comment: @BillReiss to get rid of extra reflection and save some time (not sure about benefit of this yet), but we try to improve startup time as much as possible

Comment: It's really insignificant, since it only executes once. You would need to fork the GitHub repo and maintain your own version or have the package creator change it for you. There is probably a good reason he does it this way.

Comment: @BillReiss not so much performance improvement to fork repo. Would be glad if Slodge would explain the reason for private .ctor and virtual methods.

Comment: If you are dealing with slow startup I would look at the work being done in any VM `Init()` methods long before I started doing custom startup logic.

Comment: If you open a GitHub issue and maybe make a Pull Request changing this, we are happy to merge this in so you can make your own implementation.

Comment: @Cheesebaron thanks, sounds like a good solution.

Comment: @Jammer Makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the preset time there's no way to accomplish that. As I've said above, the reason I want to do that is to improve startup performance as much as possible. What I've done already is:

- overrided FillValueConverters to specify Value Converters explicitly
- overrided FillViewTypes and filled cache on my own.

It saved around ~1.5s on start

**Update**
Thanks to @CheeseBaron, private constructor was changed to protected in next [commit](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/commit/eb522636c0ffec38a73ac527f56e17505b283204)